# Cordova : How to check if File API works?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

As I am having real troubles debugging an app in Android / iOs, can someone tell me some simple test to check if Cordova File API is loaded and works ?

Something like:

```
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            if(fileAPI){ // what can I test there ?
                 alert('File API is OK');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to request the `FileSystem`

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
                                 alert("it works");
                                 }, function (e) {
                                 alert("it doesn't work");
                                 });
```